# Applying Style To Flatpickr in VueJS Component

Tags: vue.js, flatpickr

I am trying to style the Flatpickr input box, and not sure how to apply the style.

I have a component that uses imports a Flatpickr component. I am trying to apply style in the

**Trying to apply style**

```
ComponentWithPickr.vue
```

In Template:

```
    <FlatPickr
        id="pickr"
        :classes="pickrstyle"
        v-show="false">
    </FlatPickr>
```

Style:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .pickrstyle{
      background-color: red
     }
</style>
```

**Flatpickr - has the Flatpickr code**

```
ComponentPickr.vue
```

Style:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .pickrstyle{
      background-color: red
     }
</style>
```

I've tried to add my class to `ComponentWithPickr.vue` and also in the `ComponentPickr.vue` and it's never applied.

What is the way to apply a style to a imported component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have written it, you are binding to a data property called "pickerstyle", which you have *probably* not defined on your Vue instance. If you are trying to pass a string to the "classes" prop, then you aren't binding, and therefore you don't need the `:`.

I don't know what library you are using that provides the `<FlatPickr>` component, but if it indeed does support a `classes` prop, I would assume that it is expecting either a string or an array.

I would suggest you try either this:

```html
<FlatPickr
  id="pickr"
  classes="pickrstyle"
  v-show="false">
</FlatPickr>
```

or this:

```html
<FlatPickr
  id="pickr"
  :classes="['pickrstyle']"
  v-show="false">
</FlatPickr>
```

I also noticed that you are also using the [`scoped`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Component-style-scoping-essential) attribute on your style tag. Scoped styles apply ***only to the component where they are declared***. This will scope those styles for `ComponentPickr.vue`, making them unavailable to `FlatPickr`. Removing `scoped` should make those available throughout your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried both and can see the style when I inspect in Chrome, but none of the styles are being applied. No idea why. I tried adding "!important" to no avail.

Comment: Is the `<style>` tag you shared part of `ComponentWithPickr.vue` or `ComponentPickr.vue`?

Comment: I put it in both. And I can see both getting picked up, but not applied.